# How to make a table in in a html template with app scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a table inside my email template but I am not to sure what is going on, but it is not displaying as a table in the email template. Could someone help me convert this into a table? Information is showing up as line by line but not in a table. Would like some help please.

here is my code.

```
function sendEmail2(template) {

 //setup function

 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1naSWINA8_uxeLUsj0lFntqILyDj2nirb56uvkBel79Y").getSheetByName("Sheet3");
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();



 var message = "";
 //iterate loop

 for (var i in AllValues) {

 //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 //define column to check if sent
 //var EmailSent = CurrentRow[12];

   var check = CurrentRow[12];

   if ( check == "sent"){
     continue;
 } 

 //set HTML template for information
  message +=

      "<p><b>Timestamp by: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Requester Email: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Star Rating: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Request Category: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Description: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Label: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Ticket ID: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Comment: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p><br><br>";

  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  //ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 13).setValue("sent");
}

 var SendTo = "someone@gmail.com";

 //set subject line
 var Subject = "CT IT feedback";

var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(template);
var htmlContent = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();




  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: htmlContent,
});



 };
```

Comment: Page not found?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56479763/7215091

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261174/7215091

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulling Data From Google Sheets into HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475238/pulling-data-from-google-sheets-into-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendEmail2(template) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1naSWINA8_uxeLUsj0lFntqILyDj2nirb56uvkBel79Y");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var rg=sh.getRange(StartRow,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,11);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html= '<style>th,td{border: 1px solid black;}</style><table>';
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var row=vA[i];
    if ( row[12]=="sent"){
      continue;
    } 
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Timestamp by: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[1]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Requester Email: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[2]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Star Rating: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[3]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Request Category: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[4]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Description: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[5]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Label: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[6]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Ticket ID: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[7]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Comment: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[8]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Status: </strong>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',row[9]);    
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var SendTo = "someone@gmail.com";
  var Subject = "CT IT feedback";
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:SendTo,subject: Subject,htmlBody: html});
}
```

Comment: I made a couple of changes.  Added `</tr>` and `</table>`